# How to make a UIButton insert a negative symbol in the UITextField that is selected?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton

I am creating an app for iOS8 in SWIFT that requires the user to input a negative symbol by pressing a UIButton. The keyboard I am using is the DecimalPad which does not have that option. I have multiple textfields that the button needs to work with. For example if a UITextField is selected and the user presses the "-" button then a "-" will be inserted into that textfield. I am having trouble with the UIButton knowing which UITextField is being selected.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: I'm pretty new at iOS developing but I have created the button of course that inserts the "-" symbol in a UITextField by just changing doing something as firstTextField.text = "-". However that only works if I have a "-" button next to every single textfield so that is not too efficient. I have also played around with using the "editing did begin" option that comes up after right clicking one of the UITextFields and dragging that to my insert "-" @IBAction in my code but I don't think that is the right way to go.

Comment: Have you tried my answer out yet?

Answer (score 0):

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *selectedTextField;

- (void) viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void) buttonTapped: (UIButton *) sender{
    self.selectedTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@",self.selectedTextField.text];
}

//Make sure you set the delegate of every UITextField to this UIViewController.  
//Also make sure you state that this UIViewController implements the UITextFieldDelegate protocol by inserting <UITextFieldDelegate> in the interface header.
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender{  
    self.selectedTextField = sender; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I forgot to add that I'm programming this in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

This solution takes advantage of `insertText:` to allow you to insert the "-" at wherever the current cursor position my be. Note: Makes sure to set your `UITextField` delegates to self to utilize the `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` and `textFieldDidEndEditing:` delegate methods.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var selectedTextField:UITextField?

    @IBAction func negativeButtonPress(sender: UIButton) {
        // If a text field stored in selectedTextField
        // insert "-" at the cursor position 
        if let field:UITextField = selectedTextField {
            field.insertText("-")
        }
    }

    // Sets selectedTextField to the current text field
    // when the text field begins editing
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        selectedTextField = textField
    }

    // Sets selectedTextField to the nil
    // when the text field ends editing
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        selectedTextField = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I gave it a shot but it does not seem to be working for me still even though my UITextField delegates have been set to self.

Comment: @esx0001 Are all three methods being called? (Add logs or breakpoints at the start of the methods to check.)

Comment: The negativeButtonPress is being called but the other 2 are not.

Comment: @esx0001 That seems to indicate that your delegates haven't been set since the delegate methods aren't being called... Are you sure you've set all of your text fields' delegates?

Comment: Hm so this is what I have done. For example I have a UITextField called firstTextLabel. Then I do firstTextLabel.deligate = self. I'm still pretty new to swift and iOS development so I'm not sure if this is the correct way. Thanks for the all the help though.

Comment: @esx0001 firstTextLabel.delegate = self should work, but how are you creating your text fields and where in your code are you setting the delegate?

Comment: So I have 3 textfields in my storyboard that I dragged into my viewcontroller as @ IBOutlets. Then I have 3 buttons on my storyboard (which are hidden) and from those 3 buttons I have 3 @ IBAction functions which run which run depending on if the editing did change in the corresponding textfield. Inside these functions is where I have the firstTextLabel.delegate = self reference but it doesn't seem to work. Is there any other way of going about this? I really only need the "-" to be inserted in the beginning to compensate for negative numbers.

Comment: @esx0001 Wrong place. Put `firstTextLabel.delegate = self;` in your `viewDidLoad`.